# Object inside class as attribute won't update from other attribute

Tags: python

I have been trying to find an answer to this here but couldn't.
I have an object from a different class inside a class, a valve inside a compressor station (in a gas network).

I create the valve as follows:

```
class CompressorStation(Units):
    def __init__(
        self,
        data_obj,
        configuration_obj_list,
        compressor_obj_list,
        flow_min, flow_max
    ):
        super().__init__()
        self.data_obj = data_obj
        self.id = data_obj.id
        self.frm = data_obj.frm
        self.to = data_obj.to
        self.conf_list = configuration_list
        self.compressor_list = compressor_list
        self.flow_min = self.flow_min
        self.flow_max = self.flow_max

        self.v_i_CS, self.v_o_CS = self._create_station_inlet_outlet_valves()

def _create_station_inlet_outlet_valves(self):
        
        # inlet valve
        v_i_CS = Valve(
            **{
                "cs_station_id": self.id,
                "flow_max": self.flow_max,
                "flow_min": self.flow_min,
                "id": self.id + "_v_s_inlet",
                "is_compressor_station_inlet": True,
                "pressure_differential_max": {"unit": "bar", "value": 150.0},
            }
        )
        # outlet valve
        v_o_CS = Valve(
            **{
                "cs_station_id": self.id,
                "flow_max": self.flow_max,
                "flow_min": self.flow_min,
                "id": self.id + "_v_s_outlet",
                "is_compressor_station_outlet": True,
                "pressure_differential_max": {"unit": "bar", "value": 150.0},
            }
        )
        return v_i_CS, v_o_CS
```

In a later method flow_min and flow_max from the compressor station are changed but the values are not updated within the valves, I don't understand why. Is there a way to couple these or how must the code change to be updated? I tried to define the flows in the **init** method but it is not working either.

Comment: I understand it's a problem of passing by reference instead of value but I still couldn't fix it by passing the values in mutable objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit : I just realized you can't actually pass arguments by reference during object creation like you can with a function in Python. In your case, your best option is probably to modify flow_min and flow_max setter :

```
Def set_flow_min(self, x):
    self.flow_min = x
    self.v_i_CS.flow_min = x
    self.v_o_CS.flow_min = x
```

Original answer :

I assume flow_min and flow_max are int or float ?

If that's the case, that's where your problem is. Int and float are immutables, meaning once they are created in the memory, they can't be changed.

So when you do

```
y = 2
x = y
x = x + 1

print(y)
```

2

```
print(x)
```

3

They are different, because x = y creates a copy x of y, not a reference to the same value, and therefore only the copy is incremented at x = x + 1.

By comparison, a list is a mutable, so if you do :

```
a = [1, 2]
b = a
b[0] = 3
b[1] = 4

print (a)
```

=> [3, 4]

```
print (b)
```

=> [3, 4]

You get the same, *a* has been affected by *b* change.

To change your flow_min and flow_max into mutable, you can pass them as  list which can be mutated:

```
flow_min = 3.2
```

would become :

```
flow_min = [3.2]
```

And :

```
flow_max = flow_min + 1
```

would become :

```
flow_max[0] = flow_min[0] + 1
```

It's clumsy but hey, it's python.

Let me know if this is clear.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I understood that, I tried passing the flows as list so that the values are passed by reference in the _create_station_inlet_outlet_valves but it's not working. Should the valves be constructed in a different way? Or how can they point the same reference? A programmer friend told me that it's probably not possible

Comment: Or I should probably adapt the setter method

Comment: Yes, you're right. Sorry was rusty on my Python. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

To understand what's going on you need to know one thing: primitives in python are [immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). So if you change the value of a primitive you create a new object of that type.

```
i = 10
print(id(i))
>>> 2940541299280
i += 10
print(id(i))
>>> 2940541299600
```

In the mini-example above you can observe that the id of the variable `i` changed after changing its value. This means *a new integer was created*! So now lets look at a simplified version of your code and analyze it

```
class Valve:
    def __init__(self, flow):
        self.flow = flow

class CompressorStation:
    def __init__(self, flow):
        self.flow = flow
        self.valve = Valve(self.flow)

def debug(c):
    print(f'Flow in c: {c.flow} - Flow in c.valve {c.valve.flow}')
    print(f'Flow id in c: {id(c.flow)} - Flow id in c.valve {id(c.valve.flow)}')



c = CompressorStation(10)
debug(c)
>>> Flow in c: 10 - Flow in c.valve 10
>>> Flow id in c: 2940541299280 - Flow id in c.valve 2940541299280
c.flow = 20
debug(c)
>>> Flow in c: 20 - Flow in c.valve 10
>>> Flow id in c: 2940541299600 - Flow id in c.valve 2940541299280
```

So now we see that the values behave as we saw in your example. However we also see, that this is the case because the integer **object** was changed, not the **value**.
Now that we understand what the problem is, all we have left to do is to come up with a solution to that problem. An easy fix could be to just create a
'container' class for the value. This could be done like that:

```
class Flow():
    def __init__(self, flow):
       self.value = flow
```

So if we adapt our toy example like this:

```
class Valve:
    def __init__(self, flow):
        self.flow = flow

class CompressorStation:
    def __init__(self, flow):
        self.flow = Flow(flow)
        self.valve = Valve(self.flow)
        
class Flow():
    def __init__(self, flow):
        self.value = flow
        
def debug(c):
    print(f'Flow in c: {c.flow.value} - Flow in c.valve {c.valve.flow.value}')
    print(f'Flow id in c: {id(c.flow.value)} - Flow id in c.valve {id(c.valve.flow.value)}')

c = CompressorStation(10)
debug(c)
>>> Flow in c: 10 - Flow in c.valve 10
>>> Flow id in c: 2940541299280 - Flow id in c.valve 2940541299280
c.flow.value = 20
debug(c)
>>> Flow in c: 20 - Flow in c.valve 20
>>> Flow id in c: 2940541299600 - Flow id in c.valve 2940541299600
```

We can see that the values stay the same. This is because the flow object is the same in the compressor and the valve. When accessing `flow.value` both objects access the same value and therefore as soon as `flow.value` is altered, the two objects stay updated.